# Identify swapped subtrees in a binary search trees

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am looking at this challenge:

> Suppose two subtrees in a binary search tree have been swapped, and that the BST property is broken. Devise an algorithm that identifies the two swapped subtrees in *O(n)* time.

#### My Thoughts

When an inorder traversal of a BST is done, the elements are sorted.
Now when two subtrees are swapped, the inorder traversal will
not be sorted. So if you compare the inorder traversal of the original
tree and the swapped one, it would be like you have taken two subsets
of a sorted array in the original one and swapped them.

But now the challenge comes to identify the corresponding subtrees, and I have no idea how to derive that from the inorder traversal.

Comment: Added some of my thoughts. That seems hopeful but not the exact solution

Comment: If the tree can have duplicate values, then this is not always possible. Are there duplicate values?

Comment: Yes it could have.

Comment: Then it is not possible. Imagine a tree with many nodes, that all have the same value, and then swap two subtrees... how will you know the difference? It is not possible. The tree will still be a valid BST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the tree has duplicate values and they are not always stored at the same side of their parent (that has the same value) then it is not always possible to detect a swap. Imagine a tree with the same value in many different places:

```
         ______ 8 _____
        /              \
     _ 8_           ___ 8 __
    /    \         /        \
   2      8*      8*        14   
  / \    / \     /  \      /  \
 1   3  8   8   8    8   13    15
```

This is a valid BST. And if we were to swap the two subtrees marked with an asterisk, we would end up with a valid BST, and so there is no way to detect which subtrees were swapped. It could well have been the children of the first *-node that had been swapped, or the children of the second *-node that had been swapped. There is no way to know this.

So, it is only possible to detect a swap, if the result of the swap inserts the two involved subtrees at invalid positions. One way to ensure this, is to dictate that duplicate values should always be stored at the same side (for example at the right) of the parent node that has the same value.

### Algorithm

An in-order traversal is a good idea, but the idea to then verify that the visited nodes come out in their right order is less useful.

Instead, during the traversal, keep track of the "window" (a min-max range) between which values are allowed in the currently visited subtree. As soon as you find a child that has a value outside that window, report that child node as being misplaced, and don't continue in that child's subtree (as we may assume that the subtree *itself* is a consistent BST).

If there was indeed a single swap, you will find two such anomalies.

### Code

Here is some code (actually JavaScript), assuming you have a `Node` class with the usual `value`, `left` and `right` properties, and duplicate values can only be stored at the *right* of a parent node having the same value. The function takes as argument the root node of the BST:

```js
function findSwap(root) {
    let results = []; // This array (stack) will be filled with 2 nodes
    
    // Recursive function, which will populate the array:
    function recur(node, min, max) {
        if (node.value < min || node.value >= max) { // Out of range!
            results.push(node); // log this node, and don't bother recurring deeper
        } else {
            if (node.left != null) {
                recur(node.left, min, node.value); // Narrow the window
            } 
            if (node.right != null) {
                recur(node.right, node.value, max); // Narrow the window
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Start the search with an infinite window
    recur(root, -Infinity, Infinity);
    return results; // Return the two nodes found as an array of nodes
}
```

Note that the out-of-range condition needs exactly those inequalities:

```
node.value < min || node.value >= max
```

The `min` value represents an allowable value, but the `max` does not. So the valid value range of a node is `[min, max)` (including `min`, excluding `max`). This follows from the extra requirement that duplicate values should always be stored at the *right* side. If you would decide to always store them on the *left* side, then the equality should be allowed on the `min` value and not the `max` value.

### Implementation

Below is a runnable snippet which first creates this binary search tree:

```
         ______ 8 _____
        /              \
     _ 4_           __ 12 __
    /    \         /        \
   2      6       10        14   
  / \    / \     /  \      /  \
 1   3  5   7   9    11  13    15
```

It then swaps the subtree at 6 with the subtree at 10. And finally it calls the above function and reports the result:

```js
function findSwap(root) {
    let results = [];
    
    function recur(node, min, max) {
        if (node.value < min || node.value >= max) {
            results.push(node);
        } else {
            if (node.left) {
                recur(node.left, min, node.value);
            }
            if (node.right) {
                recur(node.right, node.value, max);
            }
        }
    }
    
    recur(root, -Infinity, Infinity);
    return results;
}

// Define the Node class
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
    add(...values) { // Allow adding more than one value with one call
        for (let value of values) {
            if (value < this.value) {
                if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
                else this.left = new Node(value);
            } else {
                if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
                else this.right = new Node(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Demo:
// Create a complete binary tree with values 1 through 15
let root = new Node(8);                // root
root.add(     4,            12,        // level 1
          2,     6,     10,     14,    // level 2
        1,  3, 5,  7, 9,  11, 13, 15); // level 3

// Perform a swap of the subtree rooted in 6 and in 10:
[root.left.right, root.right.left] = [root.right.left, root.left.right];

// Call the function:
let result = findSwap(root);

// Report which subtrees were swapped
console.log(result[0].value, result[1].value); // 10, 6
```

Of course, if the tree did not have a swap of exactly two distinct subtrees, then the returned array will not always give reliable information, since it assumes that a wrongly attached subtree is itself still consistent.

But if the returned array is empty, you may conclude that the BST is fine.

## Detecting move of one subtree

In comments you gave an example of a subtree that was moved (not swapped with another):

[image]

In that case the above code will return just the misplaced subtree, but it will not give information about where this subtree came from.

If also this case should be covered, then we need to change the output, because it doesn't really help to list the other (degenerate) "subtree" as `null`. So then I propose to have the output state which is the *parent* and the *side* of the edge where the subtree was cut away.

The above algorithm could be adapted so that it will do some post processing in case there is only one anomaly found: in that case a simple binary search will find the insertion spot for that misplaced subtree. This post processing represents *O(logn)* time complexity, so it does not impact the overall linear time complexity.

Here is the adapted code, together with the example you had posted:

```js
function findSwap(root) {
    let results = [];
    
    function recur(node, parent, side, min, max) {
        if (node.value < min || node.value >= max) {
            results.push({parent, side, node});
            return;
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            recur(node.left, node, "left", min, node.value);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            recur(node.right, node, "right", node.value, max);
        }
    }
    recur(root, null, "root", -Infinity, Infinity);
    // Post processing:
    if (results.length === 1) { 
        // It was not a swap, but a move
        let value = results[0].node.value;
        // Look up the insertion point for the misplaced value (and its subtree)
        let parent = root;
        while (results.length < 2) {
            if (value < parent.value) {
                if (parent.left == null) {
                    result.push({parent, side: "left", node: null });
                } else {
                    parent = parent.left;
                }
            } else {
                if (parent.right == null) {
                    results.push({parent, side: "right", node: null });
                } else {
                    parent = parent.right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

// Define the Node class
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
    add(...values) { // Allow adding more than one value with one call
        for (let value of values) {
            if (value < this.value) {
                if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
                else this.left = new Node(value);
            } else {
                if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
                else this.right = new Node(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Demo (as in image):
let root = new Node(5);               // root
root.add(     3,            8,        // level 1
          2,     4,     7,     9);    // level 2

// Perform the move of the subtree rooted in 8, below the node 4
root.left.right.right = root.right;
root.right = null;

// Call the function:
let result = findSwap(root);

// Report which subtrees were swapped
function edgeName(edge) {
    return "the " + edge.side + " child (" + (edge.node?.value??null) + ") of node " + edge.parent.value;
}
console.log(edgeName(result[0]) + " was swapped with " + edgeName(result[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will go over it. For the duplicate part. Could be use the information `that the BST property is broken`  as mentioned in the question - The swapped BST will not be a BST that is it's BST property will be broken

Comment: Also I noticed that If we swap the whole right subtree and make it a right subtree of a leaf node in the left subtree. Then our algorithm will only detect one node.  check this tree [binary tree image](https://ibb.co/NFKKKY1)

Comment: Yes, but that is not a *swap*, it is a *move*. Your question was about swapping *"two subtrees"*.

Comment: If this is what you want, please provide what should be the output. Your question could be extended with a couple of examples, with expected output.

Comment: Are you there? I added a solution to my answer for when only a *move* occurred, not a *swap*.

Comment: Yeah. I think we can ignore move. But otherwise your solution should work. I am going over it. For swapping what I understand basically we are doing a traversal of tree and keeping the min max at each node. And we expect to hit it 2 times those were the root of the subtrees that were swapped. Correct me if I am wrong